# deeplearning4j on yarn cluster fails

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, deeplearning4j

I want to submit my jar on cluster using master=yarn-cluster , but get error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/nd4j/Nd4jRegistrator
        at Main.main(Main.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:552)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.nd4j.Nd4jRegistrator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I set sparkConf like this, using krio serializer, because i had exceptions when i run without it

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster(master).setAppName("DL4J Spark Example");
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
sparkConf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "org.nd4j.Nd4jRegistrator");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
```

dependencies in pom file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dl4j-spark_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0_spark_1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-kryo_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

it can't find Nd4jRegistrator class, but why?
When i run local this works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you didn't setup your uberjar correctly? You need to make sure to bundle everything. Your pom looks ok overall.